# Atom keeps showing node_modules folder despite all attempts to ignore it

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I deleted atom from my osx system, reinstalled the latest version.
I have a .gitignore file at the root of my project folder:

My Settings | Core has the checked setting "Exclude VCS ignored paths"

My config.cson which has:

```
"*":
  core:
    ignoredNames: [
      "node_modules"
    ]
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "one-light-ui"
      "atom-light-syntax"
    ]
  editor:
    fontSize: 13
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "asdf"
  "tree-view":
    hideVcsIgnoredFiles: true
```

I restarted atom but I can still see node_modules in my folder tree, along with .DS_Store file etc.

My .gitignore has:

```
node_modules 
node_modules/ 
build 
.DS_Store
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this looks good to me, are those files greyed out in the tree view?

Comment: @JohannesMerz no they are not, that is what is strange.  it doesn't search in the folders though which is what I wanted essentially, but I was thinking they would be invisible.